# YA SF novel with teen-only faster-than-light travel

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to recall the name of a book. No idea about the publication date, but I guess I read it roughly 10 years ago. It was a young adult sci-fi, the premise of which was that teens (no one older, maybe something about adult brains being too developed) could "jump" to another planet using technology. The group of teens that jumped were doing recon on the new planet, I think trying to infiltrate the base of another race, and there was a game of football involved somehow.

Comment: How many teens?

Comment: @Ryan A game of football - or just an enigmatic empty stadium?

Comment: Not sure about the number of teens, I think a small group at first, then maybe reinforcements later. As for the football, the characters made the ball from material from animals or plants. There was no stadium, just an open field. It was originally intended just for entertainment. Then the characters realized they could slowly inch their way to the other race's base, disguising their intentions with the game. The base was surrounded by a forcefield. It was American football, not soccer, so I guess the author was probably American. Some of this info might be a little off, my memory is hazy.

Comment: Solved! A goodreads thread figured it out. The book was Yanked! by Nancy Kress. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/101892.Yanked___David_Brin_s_Out_of_Time_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book was [*Yanked! (David Brin's Out of Time)*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/101892.Yanked___David_Brin_s_Out_of_Time_) by Nancy Kress.

> It's 2345. THE FUTURE NEEDS HEROES! They must reach back in time to find them. WHAT IF THEY COME FOR YOU? In 2345 there is no war, no pollution, no disease, no crime--but utopia has a price...